# Move div layer on click

Tags: jquery, html

I made a small and simple code that moves a div layer 200 pixles up and down. But I want it to move the layer on click instead of mouseover. mouseleave is still ok!

How do I do a check if the layer is up or down. I want to move the layer -200px only if the layer is up 200px.

```
<script>
  $(".block").mouseenter(function() {
   $(".block").animate({"bottom": "+=200px"}, 300);
  }).mouseleave(function() {
      $(".block").animate({"bottom": "-=200px"}, 200);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a class

```
<script>
  $(".block").click(function() {
   $(".block").not('.up').addClass('up').animate({"bottom": "+=200px"}, 300);
  }).mouseleave(function() {
   $(".block").filter('.up').removeClass('up').animate({"bottom": "-=200px"}, 200);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Works nice, but it keeps on going up everytime a click is being made. It doesn't know if it's up or down, and it doesn't react on mouseleave..

Comment: ye, there was an error. (`not` instead of `filter`) now it should work nicely

Comment: that worked. really sorry for being a retard and pain in the ass.. I thought that addClass 'up' says if it's up or down.. problem is when you click it and continue to click the layer continues going up instead of down. if 'up' go down on mouseleave, if down go up on click.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  var direction = 1;
  var distance = 200;
  $(".block").click(function() {
   $(".block").animate({"bottom": "+=" + direction * distance + "px"}, 300);
   direction -= direction * 2; // knew there was a formula for that :P
  });
</script>
```

That would work.

Comment: Works nicely! How can I make it go up on click but down on mouseleave. Now it only moves on click, both up and down.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using '.click' instead of '.mouseenter'?

Comment: problem is that, everytime I click inside of that layer it will move the layer up 200px. It has to know if it's up or down.